# Sprouts Came Up

Tags: grammar, meaning

I have a question about the phrase "***come up***".  According to definition 4 for "*come up*" in this [dictionary](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/come):

> defintion 4--of a plant : to first appear above the ground
>
> ex.  In the spring, when the daffodils and tulips are ***coming up*** ...

So, this:

> 1. The sprouts ***came up*** in spring.

is definitely standard English.  But is it common English?  Since "*come up*" has so many other senses, would sentence 1 be misunderstood?

Comment: Any sentence can be misunderstood. Context, pragmatics, function,  and/or  perceived speaker's intention is/are  often key. Language is communication, not dissecting sentences devoid of context.

Comment: @meatie - Samuel Jonnson's _A Dictionary of the English Language_ (regarded as the best prior to the OED) has 59 separate entries for [**come.**](https://books.google.com/books?id=DHK9D_Xz91kC&pg=PA195&lpg=PA195&dq=come+%22ben+jonson%22+dictionary&source=bl&ots=rLZAYSTSjg&sig=rSAX-OQp8mVWoeAAbrje624hbIc&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiLlZyz3YPPAhWMFR4KHRRgC-sQ6AEIOjAF#v=onepage&q=come%20%22ben%20jonson%22%20dictionary&f=false) Thus, English speakers are adept at gathering the verb's meaning from its context. It's easy when speaking of _sprouts,_ though. Did you look up that noun in your dictionary?

Comment: @P.E.Dant  So, a person not trained in farming would misunderstand "***come up***" in sentence 1?

Comment: @meatie No: A native speaker who is not a farmer would be unlikely to misunderatand that sentence. Even non-farmers know how to read a dictionary; and anyway, native speakers gather the meaning of common and widely used verbs like _come_ and _put_ and _have_ from context.

Comment: I think few English-speaking children, even young ones,  would have trouble understanding "In spring flowers come up."  "come" and "up" are words learned at a very young age, and the mechanism for putting such phrasal verbs together is in the firmware, so to speak.